# Prove: If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Prove: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges.

I want to prove this statement. I've been trying to find a way but I couldn't.
let's say $a_n$ converges to $a$ then what should i do? Can i prove it like a sequence. For example $\forall\epsilon >0, \exists N>0 \ if \ n>N \ then \ |a-L|< \epsilon$ . I don't think i can apply this to series.

Comment: Hint:
$$\sum a_n<\infty\implies a_n\to0\implies\frac1{a_n}\to\infty\implies\dots$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt what do u mean $a_n → 0$ ? How do we know the limit is 0?

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges at all then it must be the case that $a_n \to 0$, otherwise if $a_n \to a \ne 0$ then $\sum a_n$ fast approaches the divergent sum $a + a + a + \cdots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, we must have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ (otherwise it would have been divergent when we checked the limit by the divergence/limit test). Therefore, if we considered $\sum\frac{1}{a_n}$, when we take the limit, we see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}\left[\to\frac{1}{0}\right]\to\infty$$

Comment: but the div test only says whether it diverges or not. isn't it?

Comment: the divergence test says that if the limit of $a_n$ is not $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then it diverges. Now, that is exactly the same thing (the contrapositive actually) as saying that if it's not divergent (AKA convergent), then its limit IS $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges to $s$, say. Then the partial sums $S_n$ converge to a limit $s$. But we have $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1} \to s -s = 0$ by the difference of limits theorem.

So $a_n \to 0 \implies \frac{1}{a_n} \to \infty \neq 0$ so $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ can't converge by the contrapositive of $\sum a_n < \infty \implies a_n \to 0$.